# How to give different permissions for different domains

Tags: domain-access, users

I am using the domain access module in Drupal 7.

I want one domain to be accessible by anonymous users and the other domain to be accessible only by authenticated users.

How can I give the "view published content" permission to anonymous users for only one domain.

Comment: You used shared database ?

Answer (score 1):

Is seems that Domain Strict, a Domain Access submodule, may help you, as stated in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/517876):

> DA is a node access module (which is designed to enhance what 'access
>   content' means), and you should be able to do this now by using Domain
>   Strict and configuring user behaviors.
>
> Domain Strict forces people to be members of a domain in order to view
>   its content. You would enable the module, then you will note:
>
> 1) Anonymous users cannot access any content. This is because they
>   cannot be assigned to a domain (since thiey have no account).
>
> However, you can use the User Defaults setting page to assign
>   anonymous users to the primary domain.
>
> 2) Use the same User Defaults setting to assign all 'authenticated'
>   users to the domain(s) you prefer.
>
> Under this setup, anonymous users would still have the 'access
>   content' permission, but can only see nodes posted to the primary
>   domain.
>
> See section 4.10 of README.txt and the README for Domain Strict.

Check also README.txt from Domain Strict.

> [Domain Strict] it changes the default Domain Access behavior.  This
>   module makes the grants given to a user specific to the domains that
>   the user is registered to see.

You'll have to deal with User Defaults setting to set permissions for anonynmous users since initially they don't have domain assigned.